# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Ese es el error que me aparece cuando intento insertar datos desde VB a mi base de datos con el siguiente Procedimiento Almacenado.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prestar_libro
@member_no INT, @title_no INT, @isbn INT, @copy_no INT, @due_date DATETIME

AS
DECLARE @out_date DATETIME = GETDATE()

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM member
        WHERE member_no=@member_no)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El usuario especificado no existe.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM copy1
        WHERE isbn=@isbn AND copy_no=@copy_no)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El libro especificado no existe.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT expr_date FROM adult
        WHERE member_no=@member_no) < GETDATE()
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('La credencial del usuario ya expiró.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT expr_date FROM adult, juvenile
        WHERE adult_member_no=@member_no AND juvenile.member_no=@member_no) < GETDATE()
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('La credencial del usuario ya expiró.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT SUM(fine_assessed) FROM loanhist
        WHERE member_no=@member_no) < 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El usuario presenta adeudos.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loan
        WHERE member_no=@member_no) >= 4
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El usuario tiene el máximo de libros que puede pedir.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT loanable FROM item
        WHERE isbn=@isbn) = 'NO'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El libro especificado no se puede prestar.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM loan
        WHERE isbn=@isbn AND member_no=@member_no)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El préstamo que trata de dar de alta ya existe.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(@out_date < GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('La fecha del préstamo no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(@due_date < GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('La fecha de regreso no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF(SELECT on_loan FROM copy1
        WHERE isbn=@isbn AND copy_no=@copy_no) = 'SI'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El libro ya se encuentra prestado a otro usuario.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM loan
        WHERE isbn=@isbn AND member_no=@member_no)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El usuario específicado ya tiene una copia de este libro.', 16, 11)
        RETURN 1
    END

INSERT INTO loan VALUES(
@isbn,
@copy_no,
@title_no,
@member_no,
@out_date,
@due_date
)
IF(@@ERROR <> 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Error al dar de alta el préstamo en la tabla loan.', 16,     11)
    RETURN 1
END
```

GO

Al momento de querer insertar los datos desde Basic, ocurre el problema y me lanza esa leyenda. 
URGE AYUDAAAAA:( he intentado de absolutamente todo.
No sé porqué motivo me lanza ese error, sé que es porque está arrojando más de 2 valores pero sigo sin entender dónde está mi problema :c

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)

Comment: Perdón, de mi parte no lo veo 'grosero' ni 'descortés', pero si no es de tu agrado, pido una disculpa como tal. Saludos

Comment: ¿Leíste el artículo enlazado? Allí se explica con detalle por qué se considera descortés. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en las lecturas de este tipo:

```
IF(SELECT expr_date FROM adult
    WHERE member_no=@member_no) < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('La credencial del usuario ya expiró.', 16, 11)
    RETURN 1
END
```

Todas estas en donde comparas contra un valor la lista resultante del SubQuery, debes modificaras a alguna de estas dos maneras:

**Utilizar select top 1**

`IF(SELECT top 1 expr_date FROM adult
    WHERE member_no=@member_no) < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('La credencial del usuario ya expiró.', 16, 11)
    RETURN 1
END`

**Utilizar select max group by**

`IF(SELECT MAX( expr_date ) FROM adult
    WHERE member_no=@member_no
    GROUP BY member_no
  ) < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('La credencial del usuario ya expiró.', 16, 11)
    RETURN 1
END`

Comment: Otra alternativa podría ser utilizar el operador ANY. `IF GETDATE() > ANY(SELECT expr_date FROM adult
        WHERE member_no=@member_no)`