# Consulta con IIF SQL SERVER Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo una consulta SELECT bastante básica pero hay una parte donde debo definir el valor de Uso dependiendo del Mes que está guardado. Entonces, si es Mes = 1 me debe retornar el valor del campo Uso1, si es Mes = 2 sería Uso2 y si es Mes = 3 es el campo Uso3.

Lo intenté con IIF de la siguiente forma

```
BEGIN  TRAN T2
            SET @FechaFin = DATEADD (DAY, 1, @FechaFin)
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
            SELECT C.[Id]
          ,C.[IdVenta]
          ,[Mes]
          ,IIF([Mes] = '1', (SELECT [Uso1] FROM [dbo].[ConsultasUso]  C WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN [dbo].[Ventas] V  ON V.Id = C.IdVenta), (IIF([Mes] = '2', (SELECT [Uso2] FROM [dbo].[ConsultasUso]  C WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN [dbo].[Ventas] V  ON V.Id = C.IdVenta), (IIF([Mes] = '3', (SELECT [Uso3] FROM [dbo].[ConsultasUso]  C WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN [dbo].[Ventas] V  ON V.Id = C.IdVenta), NULL))))) AS Uso
          ,C.[Uso] as UsoC
          ,[Lote]
          ,[FechaCargue]
          ,C.[Estado]
    FROM [dbo].[ConsultasUso]  C WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT  JOIN [dbo].[Ventas] V  ON V.Id = C.IdVenta
    WHERE  [FechaCargue] >= @FechaInicio
    AND [FechaCargue] <= @FechaFin

COMMIT TRAN T2
```

Creí que estaba bien, pero me salta el error

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Miré la documentación de IIF y no vi errores.

Comment: Hola, por el mensaje de error que comentas, una de tus subconsultas esta devolviendo mas de una fila... entonces no se puede usar como un valor escalar en la respuesta. Revisa las subconsultas o usa el TOP 1 para que solo devuelva el primer valor.

Comment: Hola, como me dices tu funciona pero se confunde con los datos, es como si no tomara bien la validacion del mes :(

Comment: Quedaría mejor con `CASE`, y parece que no hay necesidad de volver a consultar Ventas y ConsultasUso. ¿A cuál tabla pertenece `[Mes]`?. La sintaxis es incorrecta, ya que sobran paréntesis; si indentas bien la consulta lo notarás.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267717/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)

Comment: Da la impresión de que `Uso1`, `Uso2` y `Uso3` son valores de, precisamente, las tablas de la select principal. ¿No tendría más sentido algo como `, case Mes when '1' then Uso1 when '2' then Uso2 when '3' then Use3 end as Uso` en lugar de 3 subconsultas que no filtran qué registro de `C` queremos mostrar ?